# How to load JS or CSS files with Flask, without changing `<script>` tag content?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

My Flask setup is currently like this

```
+project
  app.py
  +template
    index.html
    +script
      mn.js
```

`mn.js` looks like this:

```
alert("hello");
```

`index.html` refers to the script like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="script/mn.js">
</head>
```

`app.py` is set up like this:

```
app= Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
```

I run Flask and go to the localhost URL. But the `alert()` never fires. I see a `404` error in my browser's console stating it could not find `http://127.0.0.1:5000/script/mn.js`.

Without changing the contents of the `<script>` tag in `index.html`, how do I make Flask load `mn.js`?

Comment: Did you [read the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files)?

Comment: What would this show me?

Comment: You need to change the script tag as well as restructure your project. There is a way to include static files whiche you find it in the link shared by @jonrsharpe

Comment: Is there no way to do this without changing the `script` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `script` folder in your `project` folder and put `mn.js` in that folder.

Now update

`app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='script',  template_folder='template')`

For more details about static files in Flask you can check it http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: Still gives a 404 error